# Bind a dynamic datatable to view and get back the datatable in HttpPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am developing an Asp.Net MVC 5 application. In this, I have to display a table whose number of columns would be generated at runtime i.e. number of columns are not fixed. So, I created a datatable and displayed it on my view as shown below -

```
@model MyApps.MyModClass
@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.dtTable .Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.dtTable.Columns[i].ColumnName)
                </th>
            }
         }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.dtTable.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.dtTable.Columns)
            {
                if (col.DataType == Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))
                {
                    <td>
                        @{
                            bool val = Convert.ToBoolean(@row[col.ColumnName]);
                        }
                        @Html.CheckBox("Vote", val)
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>
                        @row[col.ColumnName]
                    </td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Result" />
}
```

In my controller, HttpGet And HttpPost methods are -

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Tally(int id)
    {
        MyModClass cls = new MyModClass ();

        cls.dtTable = cls.BuildTable(id);

        return View(cls);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Tally(MyModClass cls)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

As you see in the View code there are some checkbox columns. User will check or un-check in these cells. This complete result I have to send to controller. In my HttpPost method, I am getting the object of MyModClass but the datatable inside it is null. 
I understand that the cell value is not bind to any control so the data is not being stored in model. Each of the model's value should be bind to a control then only its value is preserved. I checked lot of posts on internet to convert this datatable to a class but all post shows this conversion assuming that the number of columns are known. But, in my case, the number of columns of the datatable are not known.
How to display this datatable in my view and How to return modified datatable to controller?

Comment: yeah i dont think you're going to be able to bind your form values to a datatable.. You might be able to find some code that can convert your formvaluecollection to a datatable and use that .. ex  `cls.dtTable = BuildTableFromFormCollection(Request.Form);`

Comment: Is there any other way to display the datatable in view? Like webgrid or something else? Displaying a datatable used to be very easy in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I had put all efforts to design my view for displaying dynamically generated columns but I did not got any solution so I considered the max number of columns as 50 and defined 100 properties (2 properties for each column) in my model.

```
public class MyModCls
{
 public bool IsColumn1Visible { get; set; }

 public string Column1Name { get; set; }

 public bool IsColumn2Visible { get; set; }

 public string Column2Name { get; set; }

 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 public bool IsColumn50Visible { get; set; }

 public string Column50Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my view while designing the table I am checking IsColumn1Visible then only draw the

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListofModCls.Count; i++)
 {
    if (Model.ListofModCls[i].IsColumn1Visible)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(d => Model.ListofModCls[i].Column1Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(d => Model.ListofModCls[i].IsColumn1Visible)
        </td>
    }
.
.
.
.
.
    if (Model.ListofModCls[i].IsColumn50Visible)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(d => Model.ListofModCls[i].Column50Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(d => Model.ListofModCls[i].IsColumn50Visible)
        </td>
     }
}
```

There are lot of drawbacks for this approach like in future if I require more than 50 columns then I will have to write code. I am sure there must be a proper way to do this but I am not able to find it.